# Checking free space on FTP server

Tags: java, ant, build, ftp

I am running a build script in which three executable files (100mb each) are uploaded to an FTP server.

The first upload can fail due to an FTP server space problem so our build process fails. This means I have to free some space from the server and run the build script again which is waste of time. I'd like to check the FTP size before uploading the exe to make sure space is there. If sufficient space is there then upload otherwise prompt user for input.

How can I check the FTP size in an ant script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135312/checking-free-space-on-ftp-server/8135434#8135434), you can write a shell script (assuming the FTP server is a linux box) along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash

FTPDIR="/path/to/ftp/dir"
echo `df -kl / | tail | awk '{print $4}'` > ${FTPDIR}/free_space.txt
```

Make sure you replace `path/to/ftp/dir` with the actual path to the directory you will be downloading from.

Add that script to the server's [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) (`crontab -e`) and let it run every hour (`0 * * * *`) or so. You can download the `free_space.txt` file which contains the hourly updated free space of the FTP server.

Comment: i have add this with which extention? can we run it through ant script

Comment: This should be ran as a shell script (`.sh`) on the server which hosts the FTP. Do you have access to this? I have zero knowledge of Ant so I can't help you with regards to that.

Comment: What was your resolution to this?

Comment: can i run manually at command prompt? bcoz i have no knowledge about servers and also i have no permission to access the server.

Comment: i m getting this error when i m running at `cmd sh ftp_space.sh` file
`df: unrecognized option `-l'
Usage: df [-aikP] [-t fstype] [+all] [+inodes] [+type fstype]
       [+kilobytes] [+portability] [path...]
awk: not found
ftp_space.sh: cannot create ftp.amphorainc.com/Releases/free_space.txt: directory nonexistent`

Comment: df: unrecognized option `-l'
Usage: df [-aikP] [-t fstype] [+all] [+inodes] [+type fstype]
       [+kilobytes] [+portability] [path...]
awk: not found
ftp_space.sh: cannot create ftp://ftp.amphorainc.com/Releases/free_space.txt: internal error: invalid argument

Comment: If you don't have access to the server then I suggest you have a discussion with the server administrator to find out how to tackle this problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5049/discussion-between-picnic4u-and-lewis-norton)

Answer (score 2):

FTP servers usually do not allow this, but you can try the command:

```
ftp> site df -kl
```

However, I suggest you to schedule a script on the FTP server which writes to a TXT file the current free space (which in turn you may read from your client).

Comment: showing Invalid command. u r suggesting that for writing script to write on txt file. so will u pls give me some clue,bcoz i donot know the ant task to find space

Comment: He's saying you can write a script which can run on the server every hour (for example) which writes the value of free space to a text file in the FTP directory. You can download and read this file to assess the free space available and have your script decide whether to upload or not. Is it the making of this script which you're having trouble grasping?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135312/checking-free-space-on-ftp-server/8135900#8135900).

Answer (score 1):

Our product, [CompleteFTP](https://enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp), allows you to add custom commands.  Custom commands can be called from any protocol (FTP, SFTP, SSH, HTTP).  In this case it'd be called as an FTP SITE command.

Custom commands can be added via embedded Javascript or via a .NET assembly.  Embedded Javascript is a lot easier to work with, so I've developed a script for you that does this:

```
function drivespace(driveLetter) {
    var driveName = driveLetter.toUpperCase() + ":\\";
    var drives = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    for (var i=0; i<drives.Length; i++) {
        var drive = drives[i];
        if (drive.Name == driveName)
            return drive.TotalFreeSpace;
    }
    throw "Could not find drive " + driveName;
}
```

Notice that, even though it's Javascript, it's calling into the .NET class, [System.IO.DriveInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).  The script is entered directly into the administration tool and is available immediately.

Here's a sample command-line session that shows it being called:

```
Connected to MyServer.
220-Complete FTP server
220 CompleteFTP v 10.1.0
530 Please login with USER and PASS
User (MyServer:(none)): myuser
331 Password required for myuser
Password:
230 User myuser logged in.
ftp> SITE drivespace C
200-170992414720
200 SITE command successful.
ftp> SITE drivespace g
501-Could not find drive G:\
501 SITE command failed.
ftp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is
ftp > df -h

Comment: please tell me the client operation system and target operation system.