# Is it possible to determine the amount of free space on a remote FTP server without using scripts?

Tags: php, windows, ftp, ftp-server

So, here is the setup I have to work with:

I have five servers total in different locations. One server is purely a web server for hosting static files. The other four servers are solely FTP servers, each containing files uploaded by users through PHP scripts.

What I want to do is be able to choose the server with the most free space available and send the next user-uploaded file to it. I've searched around, and there doesn't seem to be any way to do that with only FTP commands.

I found a question about [Determining the Free Space of an FTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8135312/5158280), which showed that it was possible to create and update a file periodically with a Linux Shell script, but, the servers I have are and will stay Windows machines.

My only solution would be to host web servers on the FTP servers with a simple index.php containing the remaining filesize determined by `disk_free_space()` but that seems a bit much for something so simple.

All that I'm looking for is a way to find out this information with FTP commands, or possibly be able to link the servers to a VPN somehow and use PHP to figure out the amount of free space, though I wouldn't know exactly how to do that, or even, if it would work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using IIS FTP server on the Windows machine, you can configure the IIS to include free disk space in the `LIST` command response.

In the IIS manager, go to your FTP site, and select *FTP Directory Browsing* applet. There, in the *Display following information in directory listing* setting, check the *Available bytes*.

Then, the `LIST` FTP command response will look like:

```
226-Directory has 27,906,826,240 bytes of disk space available.
226 Transfer complete.
```

---

You can test this with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), it can make use of this information. Just go to the [*Space available* tab](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_fsinfo#space) of the [Server and Protocol Information dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_fsinfo).

[image]

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

Other FTP servers support other ways to retrieve free disk space.
See [How to check free space in a FTP Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56060299/850848)