# How to get a response message of LIST command (from CFTPConnection)

Tags: c++, winapi, ftp, mfc, wininet

How can I get a response of `LIST` command executed with `CFTPConnection::Command()`. I can get the directory listing. But not free space size information.

Windows IIS FTP server gives free space as response of LIST command:
[How to check free space in a FTP Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56060299/850848)

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like that the [MFC `CFTPConnection` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cftpconnection-class) has an API to access the response message of the command executed.

Though as the class is just a wrapper around Win32 Wininet functions, you can use [`InternetGetLastResponseInfo` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetgetlastresponseinfow) to retrieve the response right after calling [`CFTPConnection::Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cftpconnection-class#command).

> Retrieves the last error description or server response on the thread calling this function.