# FTP server: How to send response to FTP command like SYST in active mode?

Tags: iis, ftp

I am implementing an FTP server. Suppose a client sends `PORT` command first. Then it sends `SYST` command. To which port should I send the response?

1. The client port from which `SYST` command is received
2. The client port specified in `PORT` command?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PORT` command  (as well as `PASV`, `EPRT` and `EPSV`), affect data connections only. `SYST` command, as well as majority of FTP commands, make no use of the data connection. A data connection is used by `RETR`, `STOR`, `LIST` and similar commands only.

So `PORT` (and the others) have no effect on `SYST`. You process `SYST` the same way, as if no `PORT` command was used: You send the response to the same connection, from which you have received the `SYST` command.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for fast response. Just small clarification that's why asking in comment section.

Comment: The below code does not work wih my FTP server.
pFTPConnector = InternetSession.GetFtpConnection(csHostName, UserName,Password,INTERNET_INVALID_PORT_NUMBER,false);
pFTPConnector->Command(_T("SYST"), CFtpConnection::CmdRespRead, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 1);

The below code work wih my FTP server
pFTPConnector = InternetSession.GetFtpConnection(csHostName, UserName,Password,INTERNET_INVALID_PORT_NUMBER,true);
pFTPConnector->Command(_T("SYST"), CFtpConnection::CmdRespRead, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 1);

Comment: Because by using `CmdRespRead` you tell the client to use the data connection. What is wrong. You have to use `CmdRespNone`

Comment: If you want to read the response of `SYST` command, 
see https://stackoverflow.com/q/56832223/850848

Comment: Last and final, but if we tried with cmdRespRead using Windows IIS FTP server, that code is working fine.

Comment: I do not have an explanation for that and I cannot test it now. But it's just wrong to use `CmdRespRead` for `SYST`.

Comment: But I've tested `PORT` and `SYST` against IIS 10 and it definitely does not use the data connection – The `PORT` is ignored, as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPJs4.png