# Is there a way we can find the remaining space in FTP server using ftplib?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I know we can use the size method from the FTP class to find the size of the files in the FTP server. But here I want to find the total remaining space in the server after files are uploaded so that we could guess how many more files we can upload. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really Python/ftplib question. It's more about what information does your FTP server provide.

- Some servers support commands like `AVBL` (for example Serv-U);
- or `XQUOTA` (for example WS_FTP).
- Microsoft IIS can be configured to add free disk space to the output of `LIST` command (see [Is it possible to determine the amount of free space on a remote FTP server without using scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37737361/850848)).

All these can be used from ftplib. But in general, most FTP servers do not provide any of these.

See also [How to check free space in a FTP Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56060299/850848)

Comment: Yes, if your server even supports providing the free disk space. In any case, that's not a programming question anymore.

Comment: That cannot work. And again, this is not about ftplib. It's about your FTP server. You wrote  at the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56060299/850848#56061636) that you see free disk space in WinSCP. So your FTP server does return that information. So show us WinSCP log, so that we can see what API does WinSCP use.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Once again: You wrote at the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56060299/850848#56061636) that you see free disk space in WinSCP. **So your FTP server does return that information**. So show us WinSCP log, so that we can see what API does WinSCP use.

Comment: So, any update on this?